# Convert JQuery chart to another type of chart

Tags: jquery, flot

In my page I have some charts, generated using [Jquery Flot plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/), that works fine.

But will be interesting if my client can just click in a option and the pie chart is converted to a bar chart.

Whats the best way to do it ?

It's a .Net project using MVC, so I thought that if I make 2 distinct Partial Views, each one with a chart type (a pie chart, and bar chart), can work fine, but maybe someone pass for something like this and made it simple, maybe a function to convert the pie chart to another type (in my case, a pie chart to bar chart).

Comment: @Daniel 2 Partial views, and I load each one depending what the user want. I think don't need to post a code because it's just the click function, if the user click to view a bar chart, I load the specific partial view.

Comment: There are just a few config options you need to change to get from pie to bar chart. Setup a click handler that applies these changes and redraw the chart. (But note that bar charts and pie charts are not equally suitable for every kind of data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in straight javascript; just re-init the chart with the correct options:

```
if (doPie){
   $.plot($('#placeholder'), data, {
        series: {
            pie: { 
                show: true
            }
        }
    });
} else if (doBar) {
    $.plot($('#placeholder'), [data], {
        series: {
            bars: { 
                show: true
            }
        }
    });
} else if (doLine) {
    $.plot($('#placeholder'), [data], {
        series: {
            lines: { 
                show: true
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note that how you pass the data is a litte different between bars/lines and pie chart.  A bar/line chart excepts multiple series so make it an array, `[data]`.  A pie chart excepts only a single series, `data`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtELj/).